# Making my css buttons stay in fixed place when browser is resized

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am new using css, html and jquery. I am trying to make the Simon Says game so I made 4 buttons. I am having trouble making them stay in the same "place" when i resize my browser window. I tried to use a solution in which i use jquery to everytime calculate the size of the container when the browser is resized which kinda works but I feel like it needs improvment so any suggest will be very helpful!!

```js
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var conwidth = $('.container').width()/2 - 30;
  $(".red").css('right','calc(30% + '+conwidth+'px)');
});
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var conwidth = $('.container').width()/2 - 30;
  $(".green").css('left','calc(30% + '+conwidth+'px)');
});
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var conwidth = $('.container').width()/2 - 30;
  $(".blue").css('right','calc(30% + '+conwidth+'px)');
});
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var conwidth = $('.container').width()/2 - 30;
  $(".yellow").css('left','calc(30% + '+conwidth+'px)');
});
```

```css
.container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height:80%;
    margin: auto;

}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 180px;
    border-bottom: 100px solid;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
}

.red {
    position: fixed;
    color: red;
    transform: rotate(40deg);
    right: calc(30% + 0px);
}

.green {
    position: fixed;
    color: green;
    transform: rotate(320deg);
    left:calc(30% + 0px);

}

.blue {
    position: fixed;
    color: blue;
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: rotate(140deg);
    top:calc(60%);
    right:calc(30% + 0px);
}

.yellow {
    position: fixed;
    color: yellow;
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: rotate(220deg);
    top:calc(60%);
    left:calc(30% + 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="game hide">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">
      </div>
      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">
      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems you can remove the js/jquery and just set left/right at `%50`.

Comment: I will strongly recommend you use CSS to fix the responsive look as css is much lighter than executing js. Check how to use [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). Also, check [flexblox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), those both things will help you a lot to improve the look and feel of your page

Comment: @Frankusky I did check the flexbox and it did solve my problem which made my jquery useless. Thanks allot!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the containers position to relative and give it fixed widht and height. In addition to that, try changing the card's position to absolute and move the red and blue -50%. The JS part is not needed at all.

Just keep in mind, what others said in the comments, this will give you a page that is not responsive at all and kinda "brakes" on smaller screens.

Something like this:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  border-bottom: 100px solid;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
}

.red {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  transform: rotate(40deg);
  right: calc(-50% + 0px);
}

.green {
  position: absolute;
  color: green;
  transform: rotate(320deg);
  left: calc(30% + 0px);
}

.blue {
  position: absolute;
  color: blue;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: rotate(140deg);
  top: calc(60%);
  right: calc(-50% + 0px);
}

.yellow {
  position: absolute;
  color: yellow;
  transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: rotate(220deg);
  top: calc(60%);
  left: calc(30% + 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="game hide">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green"></div>
      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow"></div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```